# How can I play Alert.startAudio() through the phone speaker?

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-jde, multimedia

I need to play `Alert.startAudio()` through the loudspeaker of a Blackberry device instead of the headset.

I know that I can change the Audio path through the `AudioPathControl` interface, but I don't know how to get an instance of AudioPathControl.

I found a [LINK](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/How_To_-_Specify_Audio_Path_Routing.html?nodeid=1326675&vernum=0) on how to do it on the Blackberry Knowledge base, but it only tells me how to do it using the Player class, which I don't want to do. Is there any way to get an instance of AudioPathControl of the current Application?

I would prefer to play a tone programmatically instead of including my own sound file. I found the following code snippet for that.

```
Player p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(javax.microedition.media.Manager.TONE_DEVICE_LOCATOR);
p.realize();
ToneControl tc = (ToneControl) p.getControl("ToneControl");
AudioPathControl apc = (AudioPathControl) p
.getControl("AudioPathControl");
apc.setAudioPath(AudioPathControl.AUDIO_PATH_HANDSFREE);
tc.setSequence(mySequence);
p.start();
```

But the problem is that `apc` is `null` and throws an `Exception`. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the section [Where Does the Sound Go?](http://books.google.com.bd/books?id=tTV9W9PmZlUC&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=AudioPathControl&source=bl&ots=7udYwIwzx_&sig=eoUyui8R_dXSsD4U2BujS7p5LvE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JyKVT_vUMYHIrQfdqpGUBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=AudioPathControl&f=false) (preview from Google Books), from **Advanced BlackBerry 6 Development By Chris King**.

Comment: That's fine. I already know how to do that. The thing is, I would prefer not to include my own music file to save space. I would prefer to programmatically play a tone instead. I've updated my question with another technique that i found but is still not working.

Comment: In your updated code, you can merge the snippet used in http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/How_To_-_Specify_Audio_Path_Routing.html?nodeid=1326675&vernum=0, i.e. iterate through all returned controls and check their type. If no Control is supported, a zero length array is returned (from API doc).